# How WordPress loads posts using rewrited URLs with no unique idetifier?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm wonder how `WordPress` or some other websites rewrite URLs without any identifier mentioned.

for example in `WP` when i open `Permalink Settings` can select a custom URL format as below.

```
http://localhost/wordpress/sample-post/
```

Just post title has been mentioned and there is no way to know the `Post ID` apparently. Now thinking of how WP know which post have to be loaded ?

What i think myself is that this formatted URL has not been rewritten and just is a sample that WordPress use to rewrite every post after i create it. So every time i write a post it adds a new rewrite to `.htaccess` file.

But this solution is not logical and make us to have a dirty `htaccess` file and is very hard to maintenance because a lot of conflicts are likely.

Another solution is to think that there is no regular rewriting at all, and `WP` is processing URL itself, so when current URL matches to sample URL it know that's time to load an specific post.

This is feasible too, but the main problem still remained that how it know which Post have to be loaded ? Is it searching on DB using title ?! So how it can guarantee that titles are unique ?

That's a big challenge in my life ;)

Comment: It is not in the htacces file. Check `/wp-includes/rewrite.php` to have an idea. IDs and titles `slugs` are unique and yes, they are checked automatically in the database. The title can be the same but never the slug (string in the link) that WP creates for each title. Additionally, WP links have relative, not absolute paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress's `wp_post` table has a column called `post_name`, which it uses to store a unique url-friendly version of the title of the post. It searches the database using this column's value.

This is typically known as a `slug`, and it must be unique.

Comment: I have a question, isn´t it faster to search for a int like 1,2,3 instead of text?